# Undefined control sequence with pgfgantt package when creating Gantt chart

Tags: tikz-pgf, errors, environments, pgfgantt

I'm attempting to make a Gantt chart in my LaTeX document with the [`pgfgantt`](http://ctan.org/pkg/pgfgantt) package. However, when I try to compile, it gives me undefined control sequence at the first `\gantttitle` between the `{7}` and `\\`:

```
\begin{ganttchart}{7}
  \gantttitle{2012}{7} \\ 
  \gantttitlelist{1,...,7}{1} \\
  \ganttgroup{Planning}{1}{1} \\
  \ganttbar{Write Wiki page}{1}{1} \\
  \ganttmilestone{Wiki page complete}{1} \\
  \ganttgroup{Coding}{2}{6} \\
  \ganttbar{Code new monitoring into the proxy}{2}{3} \\
  \ganttbar{Code new database changes}{4}{5} \\
  \ganttbar{Code new notifications{5}{6} \\
  \ganttmilestone{All new functionality complete}{6} \\
  \ganttgroup{Testing and Deployment}{6}{7} \\
  \ganttbar{Write tests}{6}{7} \\
  \ganttbar{Deploy system}{7}{7} \\
  \ganttmilestone{Complete system up and running}{7}
\end{ganttchart}
```

If I comment out the `\gantttitle`, it just gives me an error on `\ganttitlelist`. I included the `\usepackage{pgfgantt}` at the beginning.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to wrap the `ganttchart` environment *inside* a `tikzpicture` environment:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfgantt}% http://ctan.org/pkg/pgfgantt
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{ganttchart}{7}
    \gantttitle{2012}{7} \\ 
    \gantttitlelist{1,...,7}{1} \\
    \ganttgroup{Planning}{1}{1} \\
    \ganttbar{Write Wiki page}{1}{1} \\
    \ganttmilestone{Wiki page complete}{1} \\
    \ganttgroup{Coding}{2}{6} \\
    \ganttbar{Code new monitoring into the proxy}{2}{3} \\
    \ganttbar{Code new database changes}{4}{5} \\
    \ganttbar{Code new notifications}{5}{6} \\
    \ganttmilestone{All new functionality complete}{6} \\
    \ganttgroup{Testing and Deployment}{6}{7} \\
    \ganttbar{Write tests}{6}{7} \\
    \ganttbar{Deploy system}{7}{7} \\
    \ganttmilestone{Complete system up and running}{7}
  \end{ganttchart}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**Edit**: `v2.1` (or newer) of `pgfgantt` does not require embedding inside a `tikzpicture` environment.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks for your help! I wish the documentation made that clearer. Or, more likely, I need to read it more carefully :)

Comment: @Jake: You are correct - I had `v2.0` installed on my machine, but updated it this morning. Seems like `v2.1` is fresh out of the oven.